# How precisely does the election work?

Tags: support, election

I believe I understand how the nomination phase works. I would be very surprised if we had enough candidates to require a primary phase, so let's skip right ahead to the election phase.

How precisely does this work? Can we upvote and downvote, or only up? Are the two candidates with the most net upvotes elected, or is there some threshold or similar, or other more complicated details?

I'd assume there is some in-depth explanation somewhere but haven't found it. (AKA: How about linking to such an in-depth explanation from the election announcement directly, instead of having us puzzle this out ourselves or insert noise into Meta?)

Comment: Some general info. here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135360/225179

Comment: Good question, also did not really understand how the election works (my first election on CV). Will nominated candidates appear on the link that @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica shared? Also, can I chat in the chatroom about users that I think could be nominated?

Comment: @Stochastic: the link that Scortchi shared is common to all SE sites and has nothing to do with our specific election here at CV. Candidates can self-nominate at the [2020 Community Moderator Election](https://stats.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1) link in the sidebar. There is an [election chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/113762/2020-cross-validated-moderator-election-chat) for election-related chatter, so a discussion about users that need nominating would probably make most sense there.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Appreciate the clarity @StephanKolassa

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some general information about how elections work is here:

[There's an election going on. What's happening and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135360/225179)

As you say, it's unlikely we'll need the *primary* phase (we never have before).

Note that we currently need two moderators. It's possible, though, that should we find we need more before very long, the third-place candidate will be called up rather than our having a whole new election (so don't be put off standing because there are already two candidates you prefer to yourself for the job).